# Rewriting URLs with Mod-Rewrite - remove part of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm serving redirection between mobile and desktop website 
When a mobile user accesses the site, the URL needs to be modified. Part of the URL should be removed.

Here is the section which needs to be re-written:

```
/index/home#/web/  /web
```

Specifically, this part:

```
/index/home#/web/
```

Only this part should be affected.

Comment: Can you show your existing rewrite rules?

Comment: i dont have any! so basicly i need to create a new one which take off "/index/home#/web/"  when ever its part of url , the point here it should be be the full exact match

Comment: You need to do this in Javascript since server only gets part before `#` i.e. `/index/home`

Comment: can you advise @anubhava

Comment: ok, do you need Javascript code snippet for this?

Comment: @anubhava will appreciate it if you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above that this cannot be done entirely on server side as web server only gets part before # i.e. `/index/home` from your URL of `/index/home#/web/`. It needs to be handled on client side itself.

You can use this Javascript code to redirect:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("/index/home#/web/") > -1) {
   location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/index\/home#/i, ""));
}
```